# PHP - Insert data into array with single quote

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with my code and already tried to fetch data from the database and put them into an array with a single quote. However, I still don't get the desired output.

[phpMyAdmin result after run SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJcVm.png)

**My code**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT S.SKILL_NAME ,GROUP_CONCAT(SK.SKILLSET_NAME) AS SKILLSET_ALL
        FROM SKILL S
        LEFT JOIN SKILLSET SK ON S.SKILL_ID = SK.SKILL_ID
        GROUP BY S.SKILL_ID, S.SKILL_NAME";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$skillset = [];
$skillname = [];
$count = 0;
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    

if ($checkrows > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $skillname[] = $row['SKILL_NAME'];
        $skillset[] = $row['SKILLSET_ALL'];
        $count++;
    }

}
    $keys = array_keys($skillname);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($skillname); $i++) {
        $objects =
        [
            $skillname[$i] . " => '". $skillset[$i] . "'",
        ]; 
        print_r($objects);
    }
```

**What I get after print_r($objects)**

```
Array ( [0] => ANDROID STUDIO => 'Array,Array,Array,cs230,cs230' ) Array ( [0] => C# => 'Java,Eclipse,Java,Eclipse,C#' )
```

**What I need**

```
'ANDROID STUDIO' => ['cs230', 'cs230', 'Array', 'Array', 'Array'],
'C#' => ['Java', 'Eclipse', 'Java', 'Eclipse', 'C#],
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` and `for($i = 0; $i < count($skillname); $i++) {`? `$skillname[$i] =` overwrites `$skillname[] = $row['SKILL_NAME']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I looked at your [SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJcVm.png), look like you got `$row['SKILLSET_ALL']` as string not as array

Change it to array using `explode`:

```php
$skillset[] = explode(',', $row['SKILLSET_ALL'])
```

perhaps you got your desired output

Comment: omg it's work! thank youuuu. I didnt realize that the sql use string instead of array

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put the single quote right before and after `$skillset`.

```
$keys = array_keys($skillname);

for($i = 0; $i < count($skillname); $i++) {
    $objects =
    [
        $skillname[$i] . " => '". $skillset[$i] . "'",
    ]; 
    print_r($objects);
}
```

Comment: hi, I've already changed the code as you suggest (can look at the output on my question post) but it still didn't give the desired output.